# Disable the F5 debug new-Chrome-window in VS2017, version 15.7.1

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

This used to work:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/#comment-391945

After upgrading to version 15.7.1, unchecking that debug option no longer has an effect. Microsoft touts this as a "feature" when in reality it is a hindrance. Any attempt to merge the tab with an existing Chrome window, or closing the Chrome window, terminates the debug session. Supremely annoying.

Anyone out there with a new fix or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

OK I found it, the Microsoft guys added a new option, in a completely different and non-intuitive place but, well here it is:
[image: option]